# Does the PHP link() command really require elevated privileges on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, symlink, hardlink

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.link.php) says

> Note: For Windows only: This function requires PHP to run in an
>   elevated mode or with the UAC disabled.

But on my Windows 8 machine I can run `mklink /H` without elevated privileges, so I don't understand why PHP would require this. On the other hand, if I run `mklink` without the H to create a symlink, I *do* require elevated privileges, although this isn't commented on in the PHP docs for [symlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php).

I don't have a windows PHP installation, so can't test it (and I wonder how this applies for windows 7, vista, or whatever). Are the docs wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to be running as an administrator in order to create a hard link.  However, unlike in UNIX, you *do* need write access to the target of the link.

I would hazard a guess that the author of the document in question was attempting to create a hard link to a file to which only administrators had write access, and so incorrectly concluded that administrator access was necessary in order to create hard links.

Comment: Thanks. Has that always been the case since hard links were introduced in Windows?

Comment: I don't have any old systems I can test it on, but it is unlikely to have changed.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on my Windows 8.1 machine, and it appears to work fine (running via Apache/CGI)

```
<pre><?php
var_dump(file_exists('f1'));
var_dump(file_exists('f2'));

var_dump(touch('f1'));
var_dump(link('f1','f2'));

var_dump(file_exists('f1'));
var_dump(file_exists('f2'));

var_dump(file_put_contents('f1', 'test'));
var_dump(file_get_contents('f2'));
```

Output:

```
boolean false
boolean false
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
int 4
string 'test' (length=4)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is it running as a Windows service? If so, then it's probably running with the "system" account privileges (basically super-user)

Comment: @JonathanGray no, its running as a user process. Also tried `php -r "link('f1','f2');"` from a cmd window and it worked fine.

Comment: Oh, okay. It could be extended permissions on Windows 8.1 I'm assuming.